# Does HTTP CONNECT tunnel need to closed before connecting again?

Tags: sockets, proxy

I am currently trying to set up an HTTP tunnel using [Tinyproxy](https://tinyproxy.github.io/). This is the structure of my system:

Source -> Proxy -> Destination

I have successfully opened a socket to my proxy, sent the HTTP `CONNECT` request, and established a tunnel to my destination. Data sends properly back and forth, and then the proxy socket is closed. The system automatically tries to connect again once it needs to, and this time I can't issue an HTTP `CONNECT` command (Although every ~10 minutes something resets, because I am able to connect again).

Do I need to send some kind of reset command to the proxy to disconnect the HTTP tunnel? Is closing the socket connection to my proxy not enough? Wireshark analysis shows some kind of RST (reset) flag might be messing up the connection from the source to the proxy.

Edit: I believe the socket is closing gracefully. I dug into the send() function, and I am getting back `errno = 11, "Try Again"`. Which isn't a very helpful error message.

Comment: It sounds like your Source is not managing its connections correctly. Is it closing its socket connection to the proxy gracefully or abortively? Is it creating a new socket connection to the proxy before sending a new `CONNECT` request? HTTP is stateless, any HTTP client/server can close the socket connection after the HTTP response is sent. In the case of `CONNECT`, once the tunnel is closed on either end, the other party must also close its end of the tunnel. Make sure your Source is closing its socket connections cleanly, and is creating a new socket connection for each `CONNECT` request

Comment: I can't answer your question, sorry, but I have a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737261/proxy-http-tunneling-with-wininet-classes I am interested in knowing how tinyproxy does its job and what system it's running under in your solution.

Comment: Once you have issued CONNECT on a connection to a proxy, you can't re-use it to connect anywhere else, you need to just close to the proxy and re-connect.